# High memory usage on idle on Intel D-2146NT

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory

I've an Installation of Ubuntu Server 22.04 kernel 5.15 and on `SuperMicro X11SDV-8C-TP8F` with an Intel `D-2146NT` (I've also tried ubuntu 22.04 kernel 5.17 and installing ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.15 and 5.14 with the same result. To avoid this issue I need to use a kernel older than 5.14).

I have high RAM usage when idle from the server startup I cannot explain.

At startup without any services active I have nearly 6GiB of RAM used:

```
# free -m
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15663        5998        8936         155         728        9213
Swap:              0           0           0
```

Using ps the sum of RSS memory does not adds up: it shows less than 1GiB used:

```
# ps aux | awk '{sum+=$6} END {print sum / 1024}'
944.879
```

This is the meminfo output

```
cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:       16039044 kB
MemFree:         8486372 kB
MemAvailable:    9607120 kB
Buffers:           79440 kB
Cached:          1300092 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           575856 kB
Inactive:        1141004 kB
Active(anon):      24184 kB
Inactive(anon):   369940 kB
Active(file):     551672 kB
Inactive(file):   771064 kB
Unevictable:       27884 kB
Mlocked:           27884 kB
SwapTotal:       2097148 kB
SwapFree:        2097148 kB
Dirty:                36 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        365256 kB
Mapped:           304856 kB
Shmem:             50208 kB
KReclaimable:     110308 kB
Slab:             455680 kB
SReclaimable:     110308 kB
SUnreclaim:       345372 kB
KernelStack:        7664 kB
PageTables:         6352 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    10116668 kB
Committed_AS:    2497484 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       31940 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:            12800 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:      4096 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      315700 kB
DirectMap2M:    11919360 kB
DirectMap1G:     6291456 kB
```

And this is the `slabtop` header:

```
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 1095487 / 1172800 (93.4%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 28258 / 28258 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 121 / 176 (68.8%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 401911.16K / 415423.19K (96.7%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.35K / 10.62K
```

This is the `df -h` output:

```
df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              1.6G   50M  1.5G   4% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   14G  3.8G  9.0G  30% /
tmpfs                              7.7G   20K  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  127M  1.7G   7% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg0-var_log            9.8G  127M  9.2G   2% /var/log
/dev/mapper/vg0-tmp                9.8G   68K  9.3G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg0-var_tmp            9.8G   96K  9.3G   1% /var/tmp
/dev/mapper/vg0-var_lib_docker     1.7T   11G  1.6T   1% /var/lib/docker
tmpfs                              1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/2010
tmpfs                              1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/2023
```

Comment: Do you have any limitations on usable memory in effect? I'm wondering, because the entry *MemTotal*  in */proc/meminfo* only advertises ~15.5 G of memory to be available, and since `free` is using this exact same data, it announces the same amount of total memory (See the cell in row *Mem* / column *Total*) there.

Comment: I don't think so. Could be due to kB/kiB conversion?

Comment: No, because one is of base 1000 and the other of base 1024 so you wouldn't be at 1/4 of the nominal memory size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory usage was due to `irdma` Kernel Modules. I've yet to understand if it is working as intended or if it's a bug.

I've found irdma documentation [here](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/738730/README_irdma.txt)